# how to rewrite linux command to CMD syntax

Tags: linux, batch-file, cmd

Can you help me to rewrite this command/syntax from linux:

```
inname=`convert image -format "%t" info:`
convert image.jpg ..... ${inname}_%d.png
```

to batch file? It is for ImageMagick. The %d is part of ImageMagick command.

Answer (score 0):

You can create alias, the easy way

http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html

Comment: What is the CMD equivalent for linux ${inname}